# Sharepoint permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-services

this is a repost from Stack Overflow, thought some of the server fault guys might have some input on this.  Just a general question regarding permissions in Sharepoint.  Is there an open-source, free alternative  or manual method of accomplishing what the [Titus Metadata Security](http://www.titus.com/software/sharepoint/metadata.php) tool does as far as creating permissions based on metadata? This seems like a feature that should be available in Sharepoint. Any input or advice is appreciated.